# When setting up a project which uses laravel mix when running mix watch I get the same issue telling me to install sass loader over and over

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, macbookpro

npm run watch

> tailwind-href-starter-theme@1.0.0 watch
> mix watch

```
    Additional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.

    Running: npm install sass-loader@^12.1.0 sass --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps

    Finished. Please run Mix again.
```

uninstalled and re installed. Expecting mix to compile and watch the project files